# sklearn2pmml omits field names

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn2pmml

I export an instance of `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` into a pmml-file. The problem is, that the names of the fields do not appear in the pmml-file, e.g. when using the iris dataset then the original field names `['sepal length (cm)','sepal width (cm)','petal length (cm)','petal width (cm)']` do not appear. Instead only names like x1,x2, etc appear. Is there a way to get the original field names in the pmml-file?
The Following code should be runnable:

```
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml, PMMLPipeline, make_pmml_pipeline  
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
data = load_iris()
dfIris = pd.DataFrame(data=data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

ssModel = StandardScaler()
ssModel.fit(dfIris)


pipe = PMMLPipeline([("StandardScaler", ssModel)])
sklearn2pmml(pipeline=make_pmml_pipeline(pipe), pmml="ssIris.pmml")
```

In the ssIris.pmml I see this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I believe you want to fit the PMMLPipeline after initialization so you may use `pipe.fit(dfIris)` instead of fitting before the ssModel. To preserve the column names add a none preprocessing function that uses DataFrameMapper to map pandas data frame columns to different sklearn transformations before the scaler, as the pipeline expects a preprocessing function in order to keep the column names. I am not sure whether this is the best way but I checked it and it was preserving the column names.

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml, PMMLPipeline, make_pmml_pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
data = load_iris()
dfIris = pd.DataFrame(data=data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

ssModel = StandardScaler()
pipe.fit(dfIris)

pipe = PMMLPipeline([("df_mapper", 
                  DataFrameMapper([(d, None) for d in data.feature_names], 
df_out=True)), ("StandardScaler", ssModel)])
pipe.fit(dfIris)
sklearn2pmml(pipeline=make_pmml_pipeline(pipe), pmml="ssIris.pmml")
```

Answer (score 0):

The only component that comes in contact with `dfIris` data frame (holds feature name information) is the `StandardScaler.fit(X)` method. This method does not collect or store incoming feature names in any way.

The SkLearn2PMML package gets feature names from the value of the `PMMLPipeline.active_fields` attribute. Right now it's missing, which is why SkLearn2PMML falls back to default feature names "x1", "x2", .., "xn".

This attribute is automatically set during the `PMMLPipeline.fit(X, y)` method invocation. Alternatively, you may set/reset this attribute manually at any time.

If you're constructing a `PMMLPipeline` object using the `sklearn2pmml.make_pmml_pipeline` utility method, then this method also takes `active_fields` and `target_fields` arguments. Please note that in your example code you have a manually constructed `PMMLPipeline` object, which you then wrap into a new `PMMLPipeline` object using this utility function call. This is redundant, and actually masks any feature/target names that were possibly set there.

A much better example:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml, PMMLPipeline 

data = load_iris()

iris_X = DataFrame(data = data.data, columns = data.feature_names)
iris_y = None

pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
    ("ss", StandardScaler())
])
pipeline.fit(iris_X, iris_y)

sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "ssIris.pmml")
```